# Brocade ICX6610 - No 'Router-Interface ve' command

Tags: brocade

Here my problem. I need to install and configure 2 units Brocade ICX6610 as core switch. Im already done with setting up new vlan on Fortigate and some vlan dhcp pool in 6610. My problem is when i want to config ip address for vlan, there are no 'router-interface' command under vlan configuration.

---

```
LPK-ICX6610-01(config)#sh running-config

Current configuration:

!

ver 08.0.10gT7f1

!
stack unit 1

  module 1 icx6610-24-port-management-module

  module 2 icx6610-qsfp-10-port-160g-module

  module 3 icx6610-8-port-10g-dual-mode-module

  stack-trunk 1/2/1 to 1/2/2

  stack-trunk 1/2/6 to 1/2/7

  stack-port 1/2/1 1/2/6

stack enable

!
!
!
!
vlan 1 name DEFAULT-VLAN by port
!
vlan 10 name LANUSER_GF by port
 tagged ethe 1/1/3
!
vlan 20 name LANUSER_1F by port
!
vlan 100 name WLAN by port
 tagged ethe 1/1/23 to 1/1/24
 untagged ethe 1/1/12
!
!
!
!

hostname LPK-ICX6610-01

no ip dhcp-client enable

ip dhcp-server enable

!

ip dhcp-server pool vlan_100

 dhcp-default-router 192.168.100.254

 dns-server 1.9.1.9 8.8.8.8

 excluded-address 192.168.100.1 192.168.100.10

 lease 0 12 0

 network 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0

 deploy

!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!

end

LPK-ICX6610-01(config)#sh version

  Copyright (c) 1996-2014 Brocade Communications Systems, Inc. All rights 
reserved.

    UNIT 1: compiled on Dec 17 2014 at 18:25:28 labeled as FCXS08010g
                (7280225 bytes) from Primary /FCXS08010g.bin
        SW: Version 08.0.10gT7f1
  Boot-Monitor Image size = 370695, Version:10.1.00T7f5 (grz10100)
  HW: Stackable ICX6610-24*

--------------------------------------------------

LPK-ICX6610-01(config)#

LPK-ICX6610-01(config)#vlan 100

LPK-ICX6610-01(config-vlan-100)#router-interface ve 100

Invalid input -> router-interface ve 100

Type ? for a list

LPK-ICX6610-01(config-vlan-100)#
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

You're running L2 firmware (FCXS); reflash with L3 firmware (FCXR) and try again.